# Optimize and remove for loop in numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, array-broadcasting

I want to remove the for loop from the below code. In my use case, the value of `n` will be typically much larger where the value in the ranges of 200-700 is not uncommon, and it is inconvenient to list them all down, and adding one more loop would only make this more inefficient.

```
import numpy as np
n = 3
imgs = np.random.random((16,9,9,n))
transform = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(n,n))
for img in imgs:
    for channel in range(img.shape[2]):
        temp1 = img[:,:,0]
        temp2 = img[:,:,1]
        temp3 = img[:,:,2]

        temp = temp1 * transform[channel][0] + temp2 * transform[channel][1] + temp3 * transform[channel][2]

        img[:,:,channel] = temp/3
```

Any pointers will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: I assume that `img` and `image` in your code (please copy and paste from your actual code) are the same thing. --- --- That said, you cannot vectorize your inner loop because, e.g., `temp1` has an initial value in the first loop (when `channel==0`) and a different value at the end of the same loop, because you change the data segment of the array `img`, and `temp1` is just a view into that data segment. --- --- Is it possible that the code you posted is not doing what it's intended to do?

Comment: @gboffi just realized it. Edited the post, thanks for bringing it to my notice.

Comment: OK, thank you for the edit. --- --- In the inner loop, you are modifying the array on which you are operating, so you cannot vectorize the loop.  --- --- On the other hand, what you are doing (changing one operand) is really uncommon and I suspect that you just want to perform an inner product between the two arrays, `img` and `transform`.

Comment: @gboffi I think so, yes. The vague idea was there - but I could not nail it. Please see the accepted answer and my comment on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could maybe avoid the internal loop completely.

From my understanding you are taking a dot product of the `transform` matrix with the transpose of `[temp1 temp2 temp3]` matrix and then dividing it by 3.

The following is the representation of the same in an image:
[image: Image explaination]

So, all of this could actually be done outside the for loop itself. The code for that would look something like this. P.S. Also edited the variable names at some places where they felt inconsistent.

```py
import numpy as np

n = 3
imgs = np.random.random((16,9,9,n))
transform = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(n,n))

for img in imgs:
    temp_arr = img[:,:, 0:3]
    img[:,:, 0:3] = np.dot(temp_arr, np.transpose(transform))/3
```

Compared the result against yours and it gives the same output

Comment: Thank you! I was sure it was something like this, but could never pin it down.

Comment: One question. The internal loop that you are storing the `temp_arr` in, is not dependent on `n`. If I assume that `0:3` can be replaced with `0:n`, then it doesn't make sense to apply slicing, right? We can simply do a direct dot product and assign it to the `img`. Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: @srdg I am not sure what you meant by direct dot product, but if you meant you want to do `img[:,:, 0:n] = np.dot(img[:,:, 0:n], np.transpose(transform))/3`, then you sure can do that. Infact, using 0:n will make your code more consistent as it will work equally well for n-channel images.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing might not be possible to be applied in the way you think it, but with `numba` you can get something that works without having to add another for loop.

This code performs the same operation as the code you provided.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def mult_arrays_values( array, values, n):
    temp = np.zeros((array.shape[0], array.shape[1], n))
    for i in range(n):
        temp[:,:,i] = array[:,:,i] * values[i]
    return temp

n = 3
imgs = np.random.random((16,9,9,n))
transform = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=(n,n))
for img in imgs:
    for channel in range(img.shape[2]):
        temp = mult_arrays_values(img[:,:,:], transform[channel][:], n)
        temp = np.add.reduce(temp , axis=2)
        img[:,:,channel] = temp/n
```

Comment: @srdg is this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`numpy.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html#numpy-einsum)

```
In [77]: tr = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
    ...: imgs = np.arange(24).reshape((2,2,2,3)).transpose((1,0,2,3))
    ...: print('original imgs\n', imgs)
    ...: for img in imgs:
    ...:     img[:,:,:] = np.dot(img, tr.T)
    ...: print('imgs after loop\n', imgs)
    ...: imgs = np.arange(24).reshape((2,2,2,3)).transpose((1,0,2,3))
    ...: print('result of einsum\n', np.einsum('ijkl,ml', imgs, tr))
original imgs
 [[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 3  4  5]]

  [[12 13 14]
   [15 16 17]]]


 [[[ 6  7  8]
   [ 9 10 11]]

  [[18 19 20]
   [21 22 23]]]]
imgs after loop
 [[[[  5  14  23]
   [ 14  50  86]]

  [[ 41 158 275]
   [ 50 194 338]]]


 [[[ 23  86 149]
   [ 32 122 212]]

  [[ 59 230 401]
   [ 68 266 464]]]]
result of einsum
 [[[[  5  14  23]
   [ 14  50  86]]

  [[ 41 158 275]
   [ 50 194 338]]]


 [[[ 23  86 149]
   [ 32 122 212]]

  [[ 59 230 401]
   [ 68 266 464]]]]
```